# AWS Mobile Hub Localization

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-mobilehub

I'm using AWS Mobile Hub service for user sign-in. I follow mobile hub developer guide. How to apply localization in AWSAuthUIViewController. For example I want to use "Yeni hesap oluştur" instead of "Create new account" for Turkish localization. I have a localizable string for both turkish and english languages in XCode 8.3.3.

Comment: Hi, currently this is not possible, I will take it as a feature request to the team. 

As a temporary work around, you could edit the AWSUserPools.storyboard in the AWSUserPoolsSignIn.framework.